# Complex integral of non holomorphic function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I need to compute the following complex integral

$$
\int_{C(c,r)} \frac{1}{z\sqrt{-a^2+\vert z\vert^2}} dz
$$
where $a$ is real and $C(c,r)$ is the positively oriented circle with center $c$ and radius $r$. We choose the principal branch of the square root. Furthermore, we can safely assume that (as if not, the integral is easy using Cauchy) at least one of $\pm a$ lays inside of $C(c,r)$, but sometimes both may lay there.

The main difficulty lays for me in the fact that we cannot apply neither the Residue theorem nor the Cauchy integral formula because of not holomophicity of the square root. Furthermore parametrizations of $C(c,r)$ do not seem to lead to tangible results.

My intuition suggests that we will get two results depending whether both $\pm a$ or only one lies inside of $C(c,r)$ (and possibly the former is zero).

Comment: You sure you want that $|z|^2$ in the denominator and not just $z^2$?  I ask because you say that you can use Cauchy's theorem if the roots are not in the circle, but Cauchy's theorem does not apply since $|z|$ is not holomorphic.  You seem to currently believe that only the square root is preventing this from being holomorphic, but actually the $|z|$ is a bigger problem...

Comment: @StevenGubkin yes, I do want $\vert{z}\vert^2$. I did not notice that it's not holomorphic also when $\pm a$ are outside the circle. I would actually be interested in all three cases then.

Comment: Consider expanding the reciprocal squareroot into power series

Comment: I played with it some, and I do not think you are going to get a nice closed form expression.

Comment: Can you give some more context around why you need to do this integral?  Is it self-study?  A question from a course you are taking?  Or did this arise in the context of some actual math you are doing?  If it is arising as part of some other context, it would be helpful to know that context.  Maybe you really only need to bound this integral for example?

Comment: You can write $\displaystyle z = c + rw\ \mbox{where}\ \left\vert w\right\vert = 1$ or set $\displaystyle w = \expo{\ic\theta}$ which renders the integration into $\displaystyle\left(\,{0,2\pi}\,\right)$

Comment: @StevenGubkin In the research I'm conducting this integral appeared as a result some computation. Showing that it is bounded would not be very interesting as a closed form is what one would really hope for. I did not managed to get it so I gave the community a try, but your answer seems to confirm my result. And after all not every integral has a closed form.